# Smalltalk VisualWorks in Windows XP: hiding default window header buttons

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

I'm currently using Smalltalk Visualworks on Windows XP. Is there a way (and which one) to hide (prefferably) or disable window header default buttons (minimize, maximize)? As alternative: disable their events. Searched guides and Internet - no result so far (several days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use DLLCC to communicate with WinAPI's C-interface. Then you need to find a way to remove the buttons, maybe using SetWindowLong(). You can get the HWND from a VisualWorks window probably by asking for its #windowHandle.

Comment: Thanks, definitely will try that. For now I managed to find a workaround: setting "windowType" to "#dialog" in "postOpenWith:" method. That's how it looks: 
"self mainWindow windowType: #dialog."
Window behavior satisfies me for now.